# How is Visual Studio 2015 licensed for MSDN subscribers?

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 2015, and it is asking for a product key.

So, like always, I went to my msdn subscription, and asked for one.

MSDN says:

"A product key is not offered with this edition of Visual Studio. To unlock the product, you must sign in using the Microsoft account associated with your active MSDN subscription. By signing in, your IDE settings will sync across devices, and you can connect to online developer services."

uhhhhhh, we have a gold msdn, and are gold ms partners, so we should have five visual studio licenses.

How do we make this happen?

**UPDATE**: Wow, managing VS 2015 for a team is a mess. We just want a product key. But no, we must have multiple IDs built under the company msdn, go through building on line profiles for devs (who dont want those profiles, so we have to create alias emails that go to an admin). Bottom line: A couple of hours of admin time to deal with it.

Comment: Sign in with your MSDN account instead of using a product key. Product keys are no longer used with Visual Studio. You will have access on other computers by signing into Visual Studio on them, too.

Comment: I'm a bizspark member and I can add users to my organization there. There must be something similar for ms partners.

Comment: And what if your computer is NOT connected to the Internet at all, and can never be due to security reasons? I just talked to MSDN support on the phone and it was like talking to a zombie!! I'm pretty upset right now - the answer was, "you cannot get a license key"

Comment: @JohanDanforth From my experience, it is not possible to license VS 2015 unless you have an internet connection. For your reasons, and others, we find the current super tight linkage to the inet and msdn to be a BAD thing.

Comment: Even with internet it is going stale after a while. I then have to enter the password, choose between work/personal and then type the password again. Very annoying.

Comment: @r03 Yes, happens to me to. Total pita.

Comment: We have no internet access directly. There is no way around this apparently. There is no offline registration method if you are a Bizspark member.

Comment: The whole thing is a disaster. Our devs, who are always online, have to reregister vs every month or so. I only use vs two to ten times a month. Often, vs forces rereg, which takes five min for me to find creds. Huge time suck over a year. Dump vs. Use notepad++.

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft seems to be moving to a monthly subscription model for Visual Studio 2015, so licensing is linked to Microsoft accounts instead of product keys. You assign MSDN subscriptions to individual developers and they log in to Visual Studio with their Microsoft accounts.

Here's what worked for me:

1. Add a developer license. There are a few ways you can do this:

   - **If you're a BizSpark member,** add the developer through [BizSpark » Manage » Members](https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/startup/default.aspx#/manage).
   - ***Or* if you have a volume licensing agreement,** add the developer through the [Volume Licensing Service
     Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/adminhelp.aspx).
   - ***Otherwise*** you can create a [Visual Studio Online](https://visualstudio.com) project and [add developer licenses](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/assign-licenses-to-users-vs).
     <sub>This is free for up to five developers, then you can pay per developer.</sub>
2. For the developer activating the license:

   1. Follow any emailed instructions (depending how you added the license).
   2. Sign in during the Visual Studio 2015 install to activate Visual Studio.
      <sub>If it's already installed or the license isn't recognised during installation, they can update the license through Help
      » About Microsoft Visual Studio » License Status.</sub>

If you don't have MSDN, Microsoft offers [various monthly plans](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs-2015-product-editions) with [different sets of features](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx) (including a free Community edition that includes most development features).

Comment: This sounds nice except that you have an undefined amount of time until your license goes stale without internet. Their best advice is still use a key which they no longer let us do! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn950037.aspx

Comment: I have to say, the bottom line is that VS 2015 is a mess in this regard. The other day, it forced me to log in to msdn. Not pretty! (I don't use msdn for anything, and had to dig out creds, total pita)

Comment: I'm stuck with this mess too. In our case we've a correct subscription, ability to download and everything. Except VS 2015 refuses to believe me that my login has better than a trial license. Ridiculous.